# How to integration test an API protected resource requiring a subject claim

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing, openid-connect

A client application will use OpenID Connect to allow a user to grant permission to act on their behalf to access a protect resource - an API in this case. In this process, the client will get the required claims in the access token, but also the sub (or subject).

The protected API endpoint, for example:  /users/{userId}/personaldata  will ensure that the ClaimsIdentity of the client accessing this endpoint contains the Claim for a UserId of the correct value, but also that there exists a 'sub', which can only be there when a user/person authenticated.

My question is this: how can you impersonate a person for your integration tests?

I can create a test client and add the necessary claims, but there will never be a 'sub', so will always return unauthorised.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the sub was something special, but it's a claim just like the others, which can be added to the test client.

So, you can get the access token using client credentials flow for a test client. Ensure you add the required claims to the test client that will get you through the authentication of the endpoint. Also add a claim called 'sub'; doesn't matter what the value is - this will give the impression a user has authenticated.